# Why do cats meow but lions and tigers roar?

Tags: evolution, zoology, literature, feline, cat

So as far as I know the cat animals are related to each other by evolution. (Please correct me on this if I am wrong?)

How come the big cats; lions, tigers et.c. roar but smaller cats like house cats meow?

Has the evolution of meowing contra roaring been backtracked?

Is it possible to tell from the anatomy of a cat and a lion what differences cause the meowing and the roaring? Is there some peculiarities in the design of their voice boxes which cause the differences in sounds?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They have different vocal cords, differently-shaped pharynx. I would imagine that is all that explains the difference in sound. As to mewing versus roaring, the vocalizations you reference are not applied to similar sithations.  I wonder if there are videos of baby lions mewing or making similar sounds to get their monther's attention?

Comment: OMG you are right. I could youtube it. meowing lion cubs.

Comment: tiger kittens seem to meow. source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nX6XnIxPqO0

Comment: Also, cats will yowl, which (to my ear, anyway) isn't that much different from a roar, given the smaller size/higher pitch of the cat/.